# Step out of a distributed transaction for one of my Entity Framework ObjectContexts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus with Distributed Transactions.  Normally this works fantastic.  Either my message succeeds or fails.  All or nothing.

However, I am also trying to record diagnostic data to my database.  This is done on a separate ObjectContext.  For that, I would like it to save to the database regardless of the success or failure of the Distributed Transaction.

Is there a way to have one (and only one) data context connect to the database outside the distributed transaction?  (And keep the rest of them in?)

Comment: Can you simply instantiate it outside (before) the Tx scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to suppress your ambient distributed transaction for auditing:

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
{
    // Create logging context and audit your data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option (if using3.0) is to create a UoW:

http://andreasohlund.net/2011/11/21/unit-of-work-in-nservicebus-3-0/

And in there suppress the transaction and do the logging.

Answer (score 0):

NSB has a built in way to do [auditing](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing).  I would recommend turning this on and dealing with the logging/audit trail in another endpoint.